# Join using "USING" failing on w3schools tutotial database

Tags: sql, select, join

On the tutorial database found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), **where is actually possible to test commands on a pre-filled database**, I was trying the following command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers USING (CustomerID);
```

Basically: Join the tables Orders and Customers using the common column CustomerID.

I get "An unspecified error occurred." Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

On the other hand, the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders a INNER JOIN Customers b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID;
```

Comment: That should generally work. But anything else is impossible to tell without any more hints

Comment: @juergend If you follow the link, you can experiment commands on that database. I will edit the question.

Comment: 1. Don't use w3schools :) 2. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Some database engines, such as oracle, support that keyword.  Others, such as sql-server do not.

Comment: @juergend 1. So do you confirm that website is buggy? 2. Is "Microsoft" the right answer to your question? :)

Comment: Just ran SELECT * 
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers USING (CustomerID);
in the link and it works

Comment: @Nir-Z It doesn't work for me, strange! I copy-pasted your string and I keep getting the same error, on 2 different browsers... (IE & Firefox)

Comment: @Nir-Z It works for Chrome!

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: SQL has nothing to do with web browsers.  The fact that an SQL tutorial throws a syntax error with one browser and not the other indicates that the tutorial has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the database used on W3schools depends on your browser. If you use a browser that supports [WebSQL](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) (like Chrome) then `using` works. With Firefox it didn't.

Comment: Indeed, I was just about to report that with Chrome it works!!